# Can't change flex-grow on mat-expansion-panel

Tags: css, angular, flexbox

I am trying to style on my expansion panel because I want my data to be right aligned on my row.

In my style.css I tried

```
::ng-deep
/deep/
tried to target my custom class (saletotalsalestext)
!important
```

style.css

```
::ng-deep .mat-expansion-panel-header-description  {
    flex-grow: initial !important;
}
```

HTML:

```
<mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <mat-panel-title>
        {{data.name}}
    </mat-panel-title>
<mat-panel-description class="saletotalsalestext">                                      
        {{data.total_sales}}                                                                                                        
    </mat-panel-description>
</mat-expansion-panel-header>
```

Comment: no dot on ".mat-expansion-panel-header-description" as it is an element not a class. do you have display:flex on it's wrapper - I have to ask.

Comment: @CarolMcKay I have tried to remove the "dot" from .mat-expansion-panel-header-description but it is still not changing sadly. I haven't got flex on my <ng-container> no

Comment: Edit:
It works now - thanks! 
I changed the element to the right call and removed the "dot"